# Nested CAShapeLayer §Get origin?

Tags: uiview, nested, calayer, cashapelayer, cgpoint

```
for (CALayer *layer in self.view.layer.sublayers) {
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]) {
        CAShapeLayer *copy = (CAShapeLayer *)layer;

        if ([copy.name isEqualToString:@"datumSideLayer"]) {
            //get start position, get height, get width

            CGPoint startPos = copy.frame.origin;
            float width = copy.frame.size.width;
            float height = copy.frame.size.height;

            CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(startPos.x + (width/2), startPos.y);
            CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(startPos.x + (width/2), startPos.y + height);

            NSLog(@"%.1f:%.1f, %.1f:%.1f", startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

            [self drawDashedLineFrom:startPoint toEnd:endPoint inView:_thicknessUI];

            break;

        }
    }
}
```

The NSLog output is `0.0:0.0, 0.0:0.0`.

The shape layer it's nested for is instantiated strongly as a property. However, I cannot grab the origin, width or height from the frame.

EDIT: after further digging I have no frame set for my CAShapeLayer - as it's drawn by a path.

However, how can I now suit this so it's origin is able to be grabbed from the start of the path?

```
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - _plateLengthPX, tenPercent)]; // datum side start
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - capStartWidthPX - rootGapPX, tenPercent)]; // weld(cap) start
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - rootGapPX, tenPercent + _plateHeightPX - rootPrepHeightPX)]; // weld(root prep) start
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - rootGapPX, tenPercent + _plateHeightPX)]; // weld(root prep) end
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - _plateLengthPX, tenPercent + _plateHeightPX)]; // datum side end
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - _plateLengthPX, tenPercent + _plateHeightPX/2 + 10)]; // datum side end
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - _plateLengthPX + 15, tenPercent + _plateHeightPX/2 + 5)]; // datum side end
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - _plateLengthPX - 15, tenPercent + _plateHeightPX/2 - 5)]; // datum side end
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - _plateLengthPX, tenPercent + _plateHeightPX/2 - 10)]; // datum side end

_datumLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
_datumLayer.name = @"datumSideLayer";
_datumLayer.path = [path CGPath];
_datumLayer.strokeColor = [_lineColor CGColor];
_datumLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
_datumLayer.fillColor = [_shaderColor CGColor];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:_datumLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've managed to dig deep enough to find a reason for my issue.

The reason is because the frame and origin of the CAShapeLayer are not set therefore you cannot cast a §GET to retrieve their values. However, whilst instantiating the property you can set the position & bounds relative to the path you're using.

```
CGRect pathRect = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox([path CGPath]);
_datumLayer.bounds = pathRect;
_datumLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pathRect), CGRectGetMidY(pathRect));
```